# jQuery multiple selecor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm doing a poker game. I have an issue about a jQuery selectors.
Here is the code:

```
<!-- Rangée des cartes ♠ -->
<p id="1row"></p> 

<!-- Rangée des cartes ♥ -->
<p id="2row"></p> 

<!-- Rangée des cartes ♦ -->
<p id="3row"></p> 

<!-- Rangée des cartes ♣ -->
<p id="4row"></p> 

<!-- Rangée des boutons -->
<p> 
<input name="BoutonJoueur" type="submit" value="Joueur" onclick="javascript:CartesJoueur()" style="width : 180px; height : 30px" ></td>
<input name="BoutonFlop" type="submit" value="Flop" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
<input name="BoutonTurn" type="submit" value="Turn" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
<input name="BoutonRiver" type="submit" value="River" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
</p>

<!-- Rangée des cartes tirées pour Joueur, Flop, Turn, River -->
<p id="6row"></p>
```

I want to select "1row" until "4row". I did this:

```
$('p:lt(5), [src$="'+a+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
```

But it doesn't work. **I think it does p:lt(5) AND [src$="'+a+'"]'). I want WITH.** 
Could you tell me what i must modify in the selector ?
Thanks !

Comment: I tried to remove the comma. It didn't work : It didn't replace any images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/dv5cps05/3/

(Or - to see an actual image since one wasn't provided, see http://jsfiddle.net/dv5cps05/4/)

---

There are 2 problems in the code you shared:

1) As others pointed out, you need to leave out the `,` in the selector. Also, in your comment, you say the `<p>` elements contain an `<img>`, which isn't shown in your example code... So change your selector from:

```
$('p:lt(5), [src$="'+a+'"]')
```

to

```
$('p:lt(5) img[src$="'+a+'"]')
```

2) You didn't tell us what the js variable `a` was set to. Make sure it's set in your code, and that it matches the end of the `src` attribute. For this example, I just used the word "card"

Comment: Ok for the comma.  In fact my <p> elements contain <img> elements with src attribute.  I want to change the images whose name contain src$="'+a+'". Could you help me ?

Comment: See the updated fiddles, and my updated answer. They include the `<img>` elements nested in the `<p>` tags, which you appear to be adding programmatically. Either way, it will work the same

Comment: I finally bypassed the problem by covering the images in the "6row" by others. Thanks for your help Foxy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by tymeJV, remove the `,` in the jQuery selector.

Try this:

```
$('p:lt(5) [src$="'+a+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Foxygen i see what you mean. I'll show you the full code.

poker.html

```
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"> <!-- Couleur d'arrière plan -->

<!-- Rangée des cartes ♠ -->
<p id="1row"></p> 
<!-- Rangée des cartes ♥ -->
<p id="2row"></p> 
<!-- Rangée des cartes ♦ -->
<p id="3row"></p> 
<!-- Rangée des cartes ♣ -->
<p id="4row"></p> 

<!-- Rangée des boutons -->
<p> 
<input name="BoutonJoueur" type="submit" value="Joueur" onclick="javascript:CartesJoueur()" style="width : 180px; height : 30px" ></td>
<input name="BoutonFlop" type="submit" value="Flop" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
<input name="BoutonTurn" type="submit" value="Turn" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
<input name="BoutonRiver" type="submit" value="River" style="width : 180px; height : 30px"></td>
</p>

<!-- Rangée des cartes tirées pour Joueur, Flop, Turn, River -->
<p id="6row"></p> 


    <!-- Invocation de la bibliothèque jQuery --> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>


    <!-- Invocation du fichier javascript --> 
    <script src="CartesJoueur.js"></script>
    <script src="AffichageCartes.js"></script>

</BODY>
```

CartesJoueurs.js

```
function CartesJoueur()
{
var random1 = " "; // 1ere carte : variable aléatoire sur une même famille (famille ♦ par exemple)
var random2 = " "; // 2eme carte : variable aléatoire sur les symboles (♦ ♣ ♥ ♠)
var random3 = " "; // 1ere carte : variable aléatoire sur une même famille (famille ♦ par exemple)
var random4 = " "; // 2eme carte : variable aléatoire sur les symboles (♦ ♣ ♥ ♠)

random1 = getRandomInt(2, 14); //nombre aléatoire entre 2 et 14
random2 = getRandomInt(2, 14); //nombre aléatoire entre 2 et 14
random3 = getRandomInt(1, 4); //nombre aléatoire entre 1 et 4
random4 = getRandomInt(1, 4); //nombre aléatoire entre 1 et 4

if(random3 === 1)
    var string1 = "images/♠" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 2)
    var string1 = "images/♣" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 3)
    var string1 = "images/♦" + random1 + ".jpg";
else if(random3 === 4)
    var string1 = "images/♥" + random1 + ".jpg";

if(random4 === 1)
    var string2 = "images/♠" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 2)
    var string2 = "images/♣" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 3)
    var string2 = "images/♦" + random2 + ".jpg";
else if(random4 === 4)
    var string2 = "images/♥" + random2 + ".jpg";

//permet d'éviter d'avoir deux fois la même image
if(random3 === random4 && random1 === random2)
{
    random2 = getRandomInt(2, 14);
    random4 = getRandomInt(1, 4);
}

//affichage des deux images 
$('#6row').after('<img src=' + string1 + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
$('#6row').after('<img src=' + string2 + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
// console.log("hey " + random1 + " " + random3); // DEBUG

a =string1.substring(7);
b =string2.substring(7);
console.log(a);

//$('[src$="'+a+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
//$('[src$="'+b+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
$('p:lt(5) [src$="'+a+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
$('p:lt(5) [src$="'+b+'"]').replaceWith('<img src="images/backcard.png" width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');

}

function getRandom() 
{
return Math.random()
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) 
{
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

AffichageCartes.js

```
var pic = " ";
var coeur = " ";
var carreau = " ";
var treffle = " ";


for(var i=2; i<15; i++)
{
pic = "images/♠" + i + ".jpg";
coeur = "images/♥" + i + ".jpg";
carreau = "images/♦" + i + ".jpg";
treffle = "images/♣" + i + ".jpg";

$('#1row').after('<img src=' + pic + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
//after() ajoute du contenu après chaque balise ayant comme id "1row"
$('#2row').after('<img src=' + coeur + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');

$('#3row').after('<img src=' + carreau + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');

$('#4row').after('<img src=' + treffle + ' width = 118, height = 166, border=3, style = "border-color: #FFFFFF;" />');
}
```

I hope it will help to answer my question.